# How to add div to extjs object?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a javascript method. This method using div object for work. 
For example:

```
g = new Method(document.getElementById(div_id),... }).
```

How to add result of this method to Extjs tab panel ?,

```
tab.add({ html: "<div='div_id'></div>" })
```

- it's work, but I tthink is not correct.

Comment: Its okey. You can do it. Common panel will be added to the tab panel. You HTML code will be wraped by panel's body.

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you create the tab you can get the div by the following:

```
var theDiv = Ext.get("div_id");
tab.add({renderTo : theDiv }) //I believe that should work but I haven't test it.
```

So you could modify the div in your function. Then in EXT use the above method to get the div and add it to the tab.